# JEST Test Failed - TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined in CRNA Expo App

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babel-jest, create-react-native-app

I am not unit testing a fetch function so even libraries like [jest-fetch-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-fetch-mock) don't help get rid of the error. Neither does `axios` nor `isomorphic-fetch`

Running `yarn test` yields this.

[image]
My `App.test.js` simply doesn't test fetch:

```
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import App from './App'

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const rendered = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON()
  expect(rendered).toBeTruthy()
})
```

Similar to:
* [Error : Cannot read property fetch. Using jest-expo with react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111767/error-cannot-read-property-fetch-using-jest-expo-with-react-native) (might be duplicate but the question is not elaborated)
* [Jest throwing TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045195/jest-throwing-typeerror-cannot-read-property-fetch-of-undefined)

- https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/208
- facebook/jest#3499
- facebook/jest#3538

I have a fetch method in my screens(not in my tests). Note that the above error occurs whether or not I comment/use my fetch functions.

I am suspecting this has something to do with my babel or jest configs.

The above error happens with my `.babelrc` below. Changing [`.babelrc`](https://github.com/MattermarkStudios/react-native-skeleton/blob/dev/.babelrc):

```
   {
     "presets": ["babel-preset-expo", "react-native", "es2015", "react-native-dotenv"],
     "env": {
     "development": {
       "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source","module-resolver"]
      }
     }
    }
```

by removing "es2015" preset causes another error. Note this happens even if there is no `babel-preset-es2015` devDependency.

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){�PNG                                                                                             
^
  SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:318:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-navigation/src/views/Header/HeaderBackButton.js:92:223)
```

I am using `yarn 1.3.2` & `ubuntu 17.04` & `Node v9.5.0` & `create-react-native-app version: 1.0.0`

My App Component:

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react'
   import {
      TouchableHighlight,
      Text,
      View,
      AsyncStorage
   } from 'react-native'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: null
    }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    }, this._getData)
  }
  _getData = () => {
      fetch('localhost:1212')
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          data: data,
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert('There was an error fetching the secret info.')
      })
      .done()
    }
  _renderData = () => (
    <Text>You are seeing</Text>
  )
  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        {
          <Text>
            {this.state.secret ? this._renderData() : <Text>Nothing to See</Text>}
          </Text>
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```